# Prove that the only solution of the following system of equations is when all the variables are $1$.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations

Let $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_5>0$. Prove that the only solution to the following system of equations is $(1,1,1,1,1)$ (it looks complicated, but has a simple cyclic structure):

[image]

I have pasted a picture instead of writing it in LaTeX because of some parsing issues.

I am looking for nice proofs that I can generalize to the other such systems of equations that I have. Note that:

1. One particularly painful way of going about this is to substitute $x_1=a^2,x_2=b^2,\dots,x_5=e^2$. However, I don't think this is the best way, and there might be more clever ways about this. At least the arguments that I could think of were long.
2. One can directly check that $(1,1,1,1,1)$ is a solution. Hence, a way of proving this would be to show that this system of equations can have only one solution.

Comment: I'm curious, from where does this system of equations arise?

Comment: @Sahaj- It arose from trying to prove a certain inequality, and then converting that to a calculus problem.

Comment: It might be useful to define $$F(a,b,c,d,e,u) = \frac{17}2 +  \frac 12((1 + u)^2 - a^2 - b^2 - c^2 - d^2)+ u \\+ abcd - \frac6{\sqrt e}(\sqrt a + \sqrt b + \sqrt c + \sqrt d)$$ and recognize that your equations are $F(x_n,x_{n+1},x_{n+2},x_{n+3},x_{n+4}, s- x_{n+4}) = 0$ for $n=1,2,3,4,5$ where the indices are taken modulo $5$ and $s = x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5$.