# Prove that the following system of equations does not have a solution.

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, contest-math, systems-of-equations

Let $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_3>0$ such that they are all distinct.

Prove that $$(2+x_1+x_2)(2+x_3+x_4)=36$$ $$(2+x_1+x_3)(2+x_2+x_4)=36$$ $$(2+x_1+x_4)(2+x_2+x_3)=36$$

cannot have a solution.

Again note that $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ are distinct positive numbers. Without this assumption, there are solutions to this system.

This is related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4854953/prove-that-the-only-solution-of-the-following-system-of-equations-is-when-all-th?noredirect=1#comment10346747_4854953).

Comment: From $(a+b)(c+d) = (a+c)(b+d)$, expand and show that $(a-d)(b-c) = 0$.

Comment: You do not need that the $x_i$ are positive. For every solution, at least *three* of the variables are equal. This follows from taking resultants of pairs of defining polynomials. It even holds over the complex numbers, where we don't have $>0$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde- If you could write that as an answer with more details, I will accept it, and it will also help close the question.